# MATLAB, how do i print out the code I wrote

Tags: matlab, printing

I am trying to print out the code I wrote to the "command window". before I print them out, I want to remove one of the command line that I entered because I dont want it to show up at the printed paper.

1) how do I remove the command line I entered
2) is there way for me to edit the code (organize its format) before printing them out?

Comment: Have you looked into [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/diary.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete commands from the command history using right click->delete. To copy all commands from a session, right click on the date.